# in-app billing connection issue

Tags: xamarin, in-app-billing

I am trying to connect the in-app-billing but the OnConnected event not being hit.
my Android Manifest code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="alphaTestApp.alphaTestApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="alphaTestApp" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

And the Main Activity file code is.

```
[Activity(Label = "alphaTestApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private InAppBillingServiceConnection _serviceConnection;
        string publicKey = "REDACTED";

    private IList<Product> _products;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);            
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(this, publicKey);
        if (_serviceConnection == null)
        {
            Toast t = Toast.MakeText(this, "Error while connecting", ToastLength.Long);
            t.Show();
        }

        _serviceConnection.Connect();

        Toast t1 = Toast.MakeText(this, "Connected app", ToastLength.Long);
        t1.Show();

        _serviceConnection.OnConnected += () =>
        {
            Toast t2 = Toast.MakeText(this, "Retrieving Items", ToastLength.Long);
            t2.Show();
            _products = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(new List<string>   {
                "goldcoin100"
            }, ItemType.Product) as IList<Product>;

            if (_products == null)
                return;

            _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProduct(_products[0]);
        };

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            Toast t3 = Toast.MakeText(this, "Retrieving Items", ToastLength.Long);
            t3.Show();
            _products = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(new List<string>   {
                "goldcoin100"
            }, ItemType.Product) as IList<Product>;

            if (_products == null)
                return;

            _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProduct(_products[0]);
        };




    }



}
```

Comment: @EvandelaCruz: [Public keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) are -- by definition --- *public*.

Comment: @jpaugh ouch... indeed.

Comment: @EvandelaCruz It happens. Cryptography is hard!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the reason, but it would be best to set your `OnConnected` handler before you call `Connect` just in case it connects in less time than it takes for the Toast code to run.

Also, you should make the `OnConnected` handler `async` and then await on the call to `QueryInventoryAsync` (in a Lambda the `async` keyword goes before the brackets, e.g. `OnConnected += async () =>` ...). As it is, `QueryInventoryAsync` will return a `Task<IList<Product>>` so trying to convert it using as `IList<Product>` will fail and _products will always be null.

If you're running on an emulator, make sure that you've got Google Play Services installed and up-to-date. There's an article on doing this for the Xamarin Android Player here: [Installing Google Play Services in XAP](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator). Although note that `BuyProduct` shouldn't work on an emulator using real products, you'll need to use the test product IDs (e.g. `ReservedTestProductIDs.Purchased`, and note that once you've purchased this one you'll need to call `ConsumePurchase` on it before you can purchase it again).

Also, don't post your API key on an open forum.